# K2554 transistor - is it equivalent to 2SK2554?

Tags: transistors, identification

I have K2554 transistor. There is a symbol similar to Hitachi logo. I can't find datasheet for it.

[image]

Is it equivalent to 2SK2554? Can I rely on 2SK2554 datasheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite common for Japanese transistors to drop the "2S" in device markings. I'd say it's quite safe to use the Hitachi 2SK2554 datasheet.

Some examples:
[2SK553](http://www.dubuque-forsale.com/This-Month-Ads/2SK553-K553-hitachi-n-channel-mosfet-transistor.php)
[2SD655](http://oakbluffclassifieds.com/By-Year/2005/2SD655-D655-hitachi-transistor.aspx)
[2SB649/2SD669](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10pair-OR-20PCS-HITACHI-TO126-2SB649A-2SD669A-2SB649-2SD669-B649AD669A-B649-D669-/261034861238?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3cc6e3e2b6)

Comment: Can you show some examples?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a k2554 data sheet that's the first problem. However, if you have a data sheet for the 2SK2554 try searching it to see how the device part number is represented on the package - it might simply be that "K2554" is a documented abbreviation for the 2SK2554.

If that all fails then it's anyone's guess. Read the data sheet and google to death that's what I'd do.